# Dangers of 'git pull' in case the only changes to local repository come from the remote repository

Tags: git

I have a use-case where script needs to fetch a remote repository in order to get the latest revision of a specific file in this remote repository. Usual recommendations for pulling a remote repository are `git checkout master` to move to `master` branch, `git remote update -p` to fetch from remote repositories plus delete the branches which are no longer defined in the remote and finally `git merge --ff-only @{u}` to merge the changes is fast-forward is possible. However, do I need all this if my script never creates additional branches locally or never adds/commits anything. Am I correct, that in case the only changes to local repository come from the remote repository, then simply `git pull` is enough?

Comment: If you do not create commits locally on the merged branch then `git merge --ff-only` does not have any reason to fail. It still protects you from creating a different history on the local computer *if* you ever create commits locally. Without `--ff-only`, `git merge` creates merge commits if the local branch diverged from their remote counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a "merge" operation (which is implied by "pull"). To check whether a file has been updated, you can use

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/master
git diff --quiet FETCH_HEAD..last-check -- the-file || echo "changed"
git branch -f last-check FETCH_HEAD
```

#### Answers for the updated question

The "last revision" (where `the-file` has been changed) in git sense is

```
git log --format=format:%H -1 FETCH_HEAD -- the-file
```

To get the content of the file, you can use

```
git show FETCH_HEAD:the-file
```

To replace the file (and only this one file) in your working directory, use

```
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- the-file
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I do care about the content of the file. I edited my initial question.